# phpMyAdmin with SSL CA does not connect with to IPv6 MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, ssl, phpmyadmin, mariadb, ipv6

I have MariaDB server on one machine and phpMyAdmin for it on another machine (because first machine has no http server installed). MariaDB and PMA are configured to use SSL connection between them (using self-signed certificate). And everything was OK until I have migrated to IPv6 addresses.

There was two lines for SSL in my config.inc.php file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '/..../ca-cert.pem';
```

After I'd changed my configuration to use IPv6 addresses and tried to login into PMA, it has thrown  error chain: "*mysqli::real_connect(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL*", "*mysqli::real_connect(): [2002] (trying to connect via (null))*" and so on.

The partial solution was to comment the second line as following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '/..../ca-cert.pem';
```

But in this case, the Database Connection section on PMA Home Screen shows red "SSL is used without certification authority" label.

Thus, after migration to IPv6 my CA file is not accepted for some reason, although with IPv4 addresses it worked well. What can be done to solve this problem?

Additional info from PMA:

```
Server: [xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx::1] via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is used without certification authority 
Server version: 10.3.31-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 - Ubuntu 20.04
Protocol version: 10 

nginx/1.18.0
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407
PHP version: 7.2.34-24+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

phpMyAdmin version: 5.1.1
```

Comment: if you use the `mysql` client with the ssl options and the ca certificate does it connect over IPv6? I'm tying to work out if this is a PMA or PHP problem, or a MariaDB server problem.

Comment: mysql client with `--ssl-ca` or `--ssl-capath` option is connecting well. But if I use `--ssl-verify-server-cert` option, I get: _ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected._ This is rather confusing, because PMA currently does not display this error (in case of real CN mistmatch this error was displayed). I use IPv6 address as Common Name, because  I have no any other identification for this machine.

Comment: I don't think its valid in the TLS spects for CN to contain an IP, and its deprecated anyway. Given it did connect, its probably a php/phpadmin version. Suggest testing a [custom phpmyadmin container](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#customizing-configuration). This uses a php8.0 along with the [5.1.1](https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin?tab=description) phpmadmin version.